# Apache codec base64 encode/decode - not getting expected result

Tags: java, apache, encoding, base64

I did a POC using **apache codec base64** library, where I encrypted a string using SHA. (This can be ignored).

Step 1 - I printed byte array for that string.

Step 2 - Encoded the byte array and printed its value.

Step 3 - Decoded the encoded value and printed it.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MessageDigest messageDigest = null;
    String ALGORITHM = "SHA";
    try
    {
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        
        byte[] arr = "admin1!".getBytes();
        byte[] arr2 = messageDigest.digest(arr);
        
        System.out.println(arr2);
        String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(arr2);
        
        System.out.println(encoded);
        byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(encoded);
        
        System.out.println(decoded);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Expected result : Step 1 and Step 3 should produce same output. But I am not getting that.

Output :

> [B@5ca801b0
>
> 90HMfRqqpfwRJge0anZat98BTdI=
>
> [B@68d448a1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is all good and fine. Just one mistake.

`System.out.println(byteArray);` prints hashCode of byte array object. (**Note:** Arrays are object in Java not primitive type)

You should use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteArray));` instead and you will get same value for both steps 1 and 3.

As per [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(byte%5B%5D)) `Arrays.toString(byte[] a)` returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.

Your code after changes will be :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
MessageDigest messageDigest = null;
String ALGORITHM = "SHA";
try
    {
    messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    
    byte[] arr = "admin1!".getBytes();
    byte[] arr2 = messageDigest.digest(arr);
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
    String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(arr2);
    
    System.out.println(encoded);
    byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(encoded);
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(decoded));
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and output will be :

> [-9, 65, -52, 125, 26, -86, -91, -4, 17, 38, 7, -76, 106, 118, 90, -73, -33, 1, 77, -46]
>
> 90HMfRqqpfwRJge0anZat98BTdI=
>
> [-9, 65, -52, 125, 26, -86, -91, -4, 17, 38, 7, -76, 106, 118, 90, -73, -33, 1, 77, -46]

**Note** value of byte array is same.